# Windows sharing have stopped unexpectedly. Error 1331

Tags: windows

windows machines on LAN (some W7, W2k and WXP)
On December, all sharing went OK. 
Example of accessing shared folder on another machine: \\Machine2\diskf

Now, from my Machine1 (W7), I am only able to access Machine2 (what is W7).
I am  not able to access another W7 (named Machine3). Nor I am able to access Machine4 (WXP) and Machine5 (W2K).

So now it is not possible to use windows names: \\Machine3\diskc
Still, this works ok: \\192.168.8.93\diskc
(as 192.168.8.93 is local IP address of Machine3)
Of course, ping between whitchever two machines is still ok.
Also sharing Machine3 to Machine4 and vice versa and all other directions between machines is ok.

If I want from Machine1 to access folders on Machine3, machine4 and machine5, I get some of these errors (depend on the way, I am trying to use: directly by explorer, by attaching remote disk, by files commander etc)

- "Logon Failure: Account Currently Disabled" - this is probably Error 1331
- Microsoft Windows Network: network path not found. This connection have not been restored.
- system windows is unable to gain access to \\Machine3\diskc - error code 0x80004005

(sorry, errors translated to english from the czech language, not must be exact!)

In the intermediate time, I only installed Wireshark (including WinPcap) - but uninstalled. 
And I added one router to the LAN, but in "bridge" mode and there seems to be nothing suspicious.

Some direction for searching solution?
Thanks

Comment: type of networking: normal using usernames and passwords on every machine (no "windows homegroup", no "active directory" nor domain server)

Comment: Have virus and malware scans been completed on all machines? All machines been rebooted?

Comment: Scaned, rebooted, all things done. Nothing helps. And I forgot to mention, that from other machnines I am still able go to my Machine1 using \\Machine1\diskc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can still access the folder using the IP address, i.e. "\Machine3\diskc Still, this works ok: \192.168.8.93\diskc". It seems that the issue might have to do with the DNS name lookup. One test would be to add a line to the etc\hosts such as:

192.168.8.93     Machine3

Modifying hosts might be viewed as a security or maintenance problem, so this is meant as a test, not as a permanent solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand? The "Machine3" is windows-network name of computer, not a DNS name. And there must be double-backslashes before "Machine3" (so I am going to give them back to my post, as their editor is cutting them off, as I can see now!)

Comment: If you can access the machine by its IP address  but not by the network name, then the problem is name lookup failure. Perhaps the machine from which you are trying to access the other cannot reach the domain name server or it needs to have its cache of names. refreshed. See http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1600/vista_dns_cache_flush/ on how to fluch the cache.